# SQL: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ', Single_Blob) ImageData)

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting this error

> Not closed quotation mark after the character string ', Single_Blob) Image Data)"

when I run the following script in SQL Server Management Studio.

The SP, SP_Document_Upload, works fine to upload documents. I suddenly got this error when the document name contains an apostrophes in it. Example: "Here is Martins' Birth Certificate.doc". The query that I was running is:

```
EXEC SP_Document_Upload
    @ID = 1, --`Id Number of the document`
    @Name = 'Martins'' Birth Certificate.doc', 
    @Path = 'C:\temp\Martins'' Birth Certificate.doc' 
GO
```

By the way, I can able to run the select statement with out any issue:

```
Select * 
From documents
Where Name = 'Martins'' Birth Certificate.doc'
```

The dynamic SQL script in the SP_Document_Upload looks like this:

UPDATE Documents
SET Name=@Name
WHERE ID = @ID

DECLARE @sql_string nvarchar(max) = 
N'UPDATE Documents 
SET FileData = 
   (SELECT Bulkcolumn 
                      FROM Openrowset(Bulk ''' + @Path + ''', Single_Blob) Imagedata)
  WHERE DocumentID_PK = ' + CAST(@ID AS NVARCHAR(max));

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds like you have an injection problem somewhere. You should be showing us the DDL of the Procedure too, not just the `EXEC` satement.

Comment: Based on your "answer" I was write, you have an injection problem. Also `char(MAX)` isn't even a valid data type.

Comment: I used this as input to create the SP: https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/sql/sqlserver/export-documents-saved-as-blob-binary-from-sql-server/

Comment: How I can resolve the injection problem?

Comment: To solve injection problem, search for "SQL Injection". This link is a good start: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Did you mean: `'C:\temp\Here is Martins'' Birth Certificate.doc'`. Note the quote right after the 2nd backslash.